# sp_blitzcache not returning an execution plan for a long running query

Tags: sql-server

No execution plan is returned only a null value in the DMV sys.dm_exec_query_plan's query_plan column.  Any clue as to why?  I have used sp_blitzcache 'reads' and 'duration' to show the long running query but no execution plan returns.

Comment: Could it be the that plan was no longer in the cache by the time you were invoking *sp_blitzcache*?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a few reasons why queries won't show up in sys.dm_exec_query_plan, the DMV used by sp_BlitzCache:

- The query is encrypted (like an encrypted stored procedure or function)
- The server has Optimize for Ad Hoc turned on, and the query was only executed once
- The server is under memory pressure, and plans are being removed from the cache
- The plan has over 128 levels of nested elements, so sys.dm_exec_query_plan can't show it (but you can still get it via sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan if you want the text version)